# Enter Key instead of Tab Key to change the position of cursor to input type in php

Tags: javascript, php, input, tabs, enter

I am using the following code in my php pages but all what i want to is that when i press "Enter key" the cursor goes to next input type(Text) column instead of "Tab key"
Please Let me know(Also it's okay Tab key to change cursor position But Enter Key Too)
I have like 12 input type of the text so what is the shortest way to do that, sorry for making you confused. and also thank you for your help in advanced.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('paycode').focus(); 
}
</script>
<style>
#username { background-color:#F0FFF0; }
</style>
<br>
<?php if($serv == '1.EZ Cash'):?>

<center><font size="6"><b><u>Employee PayOut</u></b></font><br><br><table border="1"         cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><tr>    <td width="910" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">StoreID&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><font size="5" color="red"><b><?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?></b>
</font></td></tr></table>

<table>
<tr><td width="100" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Pay Code</font></td>    <td width="100" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Amount</font></td><td width="146" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Date</font></td><td width="150" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Memo</font></td><td width="150" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Account type</font></td><td width="250" align="center" bgcolor="d6d6d6"><font size="5">Account type</font></td></tr>
</table>

<style>
[required] {
border-color: #88a;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 255, .5);
}
:invalid {
border-color: #e88;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);
}
</style>

<form method="post" action="commit.php"><table border = "0" width="330">

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width:   100px" ></td>
<script>

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode==13) {
    $(this).next('input').focus();
}
});

</script>
<script type="text/Javascript"  src="Javascript/core.js"></script>

 <td align = "center"><font size="4">
 <input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width:  100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"><input type="hidden" size="25"  name="cash[]" id='cash'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=""></td

 </td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]"  id='amount'   style="height: 30px; width:  100px" ></td>

 <td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width:   100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date;   ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011"  style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>   </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001"  style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width:   100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width:   100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width:  100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font- size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date;   ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>  </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
 <input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px;  width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width:  100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
 <input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>   </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>  </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>    

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>   </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>    

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>  </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option> </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width:   100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option></td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>   </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option></td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>    </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

<tr><td align = "center"><font size="4">
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="paycode[]" id='paycode'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="sid[]" id='sid'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value="<?php  $serv=$_POST['serv'];echo $serv ;?>"></td

</td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="amount[]" id='amount'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px"></td>

<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="hidden" size="25" name="check[]" id='check'  style="height: 30px; width: 100px" value=''></td>

<td><input type="date" size="35" name="date[]" style="height: 30px; width: 146px; font-size: 15" min="2010-08-14" max="2020-08-14" value="<?php $serv=$_POST['date']; echo $date; ?>"/></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4">
<input type="text" size="25" name="memo[]" id='memo'  style="height: 30px; width: 150px"></td>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc1[]" style="height: 30px; width: 150px">
<option value="10011" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;10011: EZ Cash</option>  </td></seclect>
<td align = "center"><font size="4"><select name="acc2[]" style="height: 30px; width: 250px">
<option value="66001" style="background-color: #F8E0F7">&nbsp;66001: EZ Employee Payroll</option></select></td></tr>

</table>

<center>
<br><div><input type="hidden" name="tot" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"> <input      type="hidden" name="stid" value="<?php echo $serv; ?>"><input value="Back" onclick="history.go(-1);" type="button" style = "height:40; width:90">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" style = "height:40; width:90" value="Next"/>

<?php endif;?>
```

Thqank you again!

Comment: There is way too much code here. Please remove code that is not relevant to your question, so that we only see the minimal amount necessary for us to answer the question.

Comment: You must have some JavaScript that is causing the problem. `Enter` should submit the form.

Comment: Using the TAB key is the standard way of moving from one form element to another in most browsers. Changing how it is done will only confuse your users. It is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general concept:

```
onkeydown = function(ev){
  var e = ev || event;
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    return false;
  }
  // Element.focus();
}
```